# Datepicker not working in safari and FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, safari

I'm trying to use the default date type in HTML5, but this is not fully supported by Safari and FireFox, my workaround using jQuery is also not working.

I have this in `script.js`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ( $('#date1').type != 'date' ) $('#date1').datepicker();
});
```

In the form, I have this:

```
<script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<input id="date1" name="date1" required="required" type="date" value="MM/DD/YY"/>
```

When I load the page in Safari/Firefox, I see no error, I also inspect elements, no error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you create a fiddle that works with this?  Is it something as easy as not including the jquery UI components for datepicker?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, really. Do you want to use the HTML5 if available and use jQuery UI's datepicker as a fallback? What error are you expecting?

Comment: @Tom Did you read the question?

Comment: I did like five times but the real question is not there. Anyways, check the answer and be happy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JQuery has a `.type` function, however it is not being properly used in your example, nor is it relevant. What I believe you want is the element's `type` *property*, which can be achieved like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ( $('#date1').prop('type') != 'date' ) $('#date1').datepicker();
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle comparing `.type` to `.prop('type')`: https://jsfiddle.net/hczg6uyf/1/

Here is a JSFiddle of your fixed code, supplied by Tom in the comments below: https://jsfiddle.net/51wLrxy0/1/

Answer (score 1):

Well after reading that this is not supported on Safari and IE , i got a work around that im happy with.

My problem is that on Safari i could not even click on the input field. So user cant even manually add a date, and if he could there was no placeholder text to tell him its a date input field.

**My Sulotion:**

Add a placeholder, chrome will ignore this. Then also add a `min-height` to the input and then on Safari i can at least see its a date input field and the user can add a date manually.

**Code:**

```
<input placeholder="Date" id="datetimepicker" type="date" name="calender" class="form-control" />
```

**CSS:**

```
input#datetimepicker {
   min-height: 1px;   
}
```

This is just a quick hack that worked for me as for the browsers that doesnt support `type="date"` .